# Dell Latitude Laptop freezing

Tags: laptop, freeze, crash

Dell Latitude E5570 Windows 10 Pro Version: 10.0.18362 Out of Warranty Intel Core i5-6440HQ CPU 2.60GHz Bios:Dell Inc 1.21.6 02/10/2019 8GB RAM Hard Drive 250GB SSD

Issue: Crash/Freeze with no blue screen (whatever is on the screen is stuck) (it blue screened once: Kernal_Data_Inpage_Error), stuck cursor, keyboard lights are on. Non-reponsive with screen on. Forcing you to restart to use it. It also crashes in the BIOS.

What I have tried: Changed HDD to another SSD. Changed RAM. Updated Bios.

But the issue persists. If any of you know what the issue could be can you please advise.

Comment: You said "Changed HDD to another SSD. Changed RAM. Updated Bios."   So you changed OS (drive change) and so it must be hardware:  Motherboard or CPU

Comment: Good.  If I post my comment as an Answer - will you accept it?

Comment: sure, why not, The issue is a tough one

Comment: Run the hardware diagnostics from the bios, run the extended test>>>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/article/ht/en/htdhs1/sln114988/dell-diagnostic-tools-to-diagnose-and-fix-hardware-problems-on-your-dell-pc-tablet-or-servers?lang=en

Comment: I saw above that the machine crashes in BIOS as well which makes me think motherboard or CPU

Answer (score 1):

You said "Changed HDD to another SSD. Changed RAM. Updated Bios." So you changed OS (drive change) and so I think now that it must be hardware: Motherboard or CPU. Everything else has been ruled out